# How to say, want something from someone or to use someone (negative meaning)

Tags: expressions

How would someone say, someone just wants something from me/you/him/her with a negative nuance. For example, "No one speaks to me unless they want something from me." Or, "I thought she liked me, but she was just using me." I believe I can explain this in Japanese, but I guess I am looking for specific words or word phrases that more clearly express this kind of meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question since there's not really any right or wrong answers here; do you want idioms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [目的]{もくてき}, eg:

> 「みんな、なにか**目的**があって私に近づいてくるのよ。」

[利用]{りよう}する, eg:

> 「友達だと思ってたのに、実は私のこと**利用し**てただけだったのね。」

[企]{たくら}む, eg:

> 「私と仲良くなろうとする人なんて、なにか**企ん**でるに決まってる。」

or ～～(が)[目当]{めあ}て, eg:

> 「みんな俺の[金]{かね}(が)**目当て**で、俺に話しかけてくるんだ。」
>   「私に近づいてきたのは、最初から私の[体]{からだ}(が)**目当て**だったのね！」

or maybe [下心]{したごころ}がある, eg:

> 「彼は、**下心があって**私に近づいてきたのよ。」(usually with sexual connotation)