# 目当てにさらに Meaning

Tags: meaning, translation

Context: In a manga, the characters are being attacked and after character X is volunteered to take care of them and does so through persuasion, someone says this line

> X目当て{めあて}にさらに(enemies)が！

My grasp of the sentence is roughly "Even more enemies for X!" What I'm wondering is if 目当て is trying to express something like that, "X can handle even more", or something else? None of the dictionary definitions as I understand them seem to fit the situation exactly, with "君は彼目当てにして良い/You can rely on him." seeming closest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of meanings of [目当て](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6/) is "target", or "something conspicuous that you eagerly look for".

> **２** 心の中で目指しているもの。行動のねらい。目的。「目当ての品」「金目当て」

X目当てに literally means "with X as the target", an adverbial phrase that qualifies a verb, which is omitted in this sentence, but easily assumed as 来る or something like that.

> X目当てにさらに (enemies) が [omitted verb]！
>   → "(Enemies) [omitted verb] in addition, eagerly targeting X!"
>   → "Even more (enemies) [omitted verb] for X!"
>   → *(Enemies) reinforcement attracted by X!*

Somewhat related answer in: [How to say, want something from someone or to use someone (negative meaning)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43969/7810)

Comment: I see! That makes much more sense. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

the 目当 characters translates to "see at this spot/point". It does not say anything about "more". I think the character says that "do it mr.x attack the enemy in front of you"